# Azure internal load balancer issue

Tags: load-balancing, azure

I've faced with problem that I can't connect to Azure ILB port from VM in the backend.
eg. Created ILB (10.0.0.100) with 1 VM (backend_vm) as backend and open port, say 1111.
Other VMs can telnet on 10.0.0.100 1111 nice, but VM (backend_vm) can't connect to 10.0.0.100 1111. No firewalls, security groups in IF allows connections from ANY source ...

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I test in my lab. I meet same issue with you. If I `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` on the two VMs. It works. When I test in other VMs, it also works. However, when I `telnet loadbalanceinternalip 80` in the pool member VMs.  It connects timeout on one VM.

Based on my knowledge, it is a except behavior. Internal load balancer configurations do not offer SNAT today. In turn, an internal load balancer configuration does not allow a pool member to access the IP address of the internal load balancer.